# Form filling and pressing javascript buttons in python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, mechanize, jython

I want to automate form filling on a website with information of certain parameters that will return products based on the parameters I enter. I tried using mechanize in python but it does not support javascript and it seems like in order to navigate the entire process of filling in parameters requires pressing some buttons that seem like javascript objects. For instance the Guided Selection button:

```
    <a onclick="_gaq.push([&#39;_trackEvent&#39;, &#39;Navigation Menu&#39;, &#39;Click&#39;, &#39;Guided Selection Link&#39;]);" id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_ConfigureLink" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$NavigationMenu$ConfigureLink&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Guided Selection</a></li>
```

I also tried using selenium but I do not want to create a new instance of a browser. Any python based suggestions? Perhaps jython? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try using `self.driver.execute_script("__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$NavigationMenu$ConfigureLink&#39;,&#39;&#39;)")`?

Comment: Sorry is that for mechanize? Because I have no real issues clicking those buttons with Selenium. I can just look at the page source and click the name by id or name using driver.find_element_by_id("some_id").click()

Comment: Sorry that was a Selenium python binding to allow you to just execute the javascript. I didn't realise you were looking for a non Selenium solution, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to simply capture the form information using a tool like firebug. And then "replay" the request (whether it's GET or POST) through Python. Here is a snippet for a POST request.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

In fire bug you can get the `url` and `values` from under the console tab.

[image]

This probably won't work if you are doing automated form discovery.

Comment: Thanks, but I decided to just use selenium